# Ros1_bridge between ROS1 on WSL and ROS2 on Windows

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello !

I would like to set up a system in which I would have (on a single computer of course) :

- ROS Kinetic installed on WSL (could also be ROS Melodic),
- ROS2 Dashing on pure Windows,
- ros1_bridge to allow communication between the first two.

Would you say it's feasible ?

**What I really want to do:**

I am currently working with [OnBoard-SDK-ROS](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Onboard-SDK-ROS), a package designed to connect ROS to DJI's drones. I would like to synchronize data from various sensors with my drone ones' (using ROS of course). My problem is that those sensors can only be connected to Windows (*cry in Linux...*).

Of course, I could have OnBoard-SDK-ROS on my WSL and some kind of web-server on Windows to expose sensors data to WSL. But it bothers me to lost ROS abilities.

At first, I thought of installing both ROS1 and ROS2 on Windows. But I am experiencing a lot of troubles trying to compile [OnBoard-SDK](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Onboard-SDK) on Windows (dependency of OnBoard-SDK-ROS). I am not even sure that it is possible.

Any thoughts/ideas would be greatly appreciated !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343250/ros1_bridge-between-ros1-on-wsl-and-ros2-on-windows/) by [erenaud2](https://answers.ros.org/users/51469/erenaud2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2020-02-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MCornelis](https://answers.ros.org/users/44213/mcornelis/) on 2020-02-06**:
So where do you want to have the ros1_bridge running?

What is feasible is to have ROS1 and a minimal ROS2 install with the ros1_bridge on each robot/drone. They will all publish in the global DDS dataspace and a single computer running ROS2 can see all the data from all the robots/drones (make sure you namespace all the topics published by the robots).

**Comment by [MCornelis](https://answers.ros.org/users/44213/mcornelis/) on 2020-02-06**:
If you want the ros1_bridge to run on the host, then you can only connect to one drone by specifying the ROS master on the drone. To be able to compile the ros1_bridge you will need to have both ROS1 and ROS2 installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@MCornelis Sorry, I didn't make my self clear. ROS is NOT installed on my drone (and can NOT be). It only contains a flight controller on which I can't do anything. I have one single computer embedded on my drone and that's it, really.

I have been playing around with ros1_bridge since I post this issue and now I get how it works. At first, I didn't realize I had to have both ROS1 and ROS2 installed on my machine, as you pointed out. So I tried to make it work on Linux, which I easily achieved.

Then, I try to solve my original issue. Here what I had a mind:

1. Install ROS1 Melodic on WSL
2. Install both ROS1 Melodic and ROS2 Eloquent on Windows (ROS1 melodic being used only for ros1_bridge compilation)
3. Build ros1_bridge from source on Windows and launch a dynamic_bridge
4. Launch a dummy ROS2 publisher on Windows
5. Launch a dummy ROS1 listener on WSL (and pray to see my messages...)

This didn't work because of step 3. Compiling ros1_bridge on Windows is really painful. So I was ready to give up and implement some kind of RESTful API using Flask, when I literally had an epiphany...
What if instead of building ros1_bridge on Windows, I build it on WSL ? It would imply having ROS2 Eloquent installed both on Windows and Linux, but it isn't such a big deal...

So here what I did :

1. Install both ROS1 Melodic and ROS2 Eloquent on WSL (ROS2 being used only for ros1_bridge compilation)
2. Install ROS2 Eloquent on Windows
3. Build ros1_bridge from source on WSL and launch a dynamic_bridge (from WSL of course)
4. Launch a dummy ROS1 publisher on WSL
5. Launch a dummy ROS2 listener on Windows and to my huge surprise, I was seeing messages coming from WSL ! Without any extra configurations ! Gotta love ROS and WSL !

PS: I didn't specify why I needed to have ROS2 on Windows : that's because I am using python 3.7 to talk with the sensors connected to my embedded computer. On the other hand, DJI didn't make any ROS2 package for their drones, so I was stuck with ROS1 and python2.7...

---

Originally posted by [erenaud2](https://answers.ros.org/users/51469/erenaud2/) with karma: 26 on 2020-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [erenaud2](https://answers.ros.org/users/51469/erenaud2/) on 2020-02-12**:
Unfortunately, I can not accept my answer as correct since my karma is < 10 points